# Re-use vmsplice buffer when not gifting to kernel

Tags: c, linux, splice

I am trying to understand how `vmsplice` works, especially when it comes to buffer re-use. In the example below, I have passed no flag so normally `vmsplice` should be blocking and the kernel is not "gifted" the buffer. However, when the sleep is commented out, the output becomes completely unordered. What am I missing?

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE 
#include <bits/types/struct_iovec.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[2] = "0\n";
    struct iovec iov;
    iov.iov_base = buffer;
    iov.iov_len = 2;
    while (1) {
        buffer[0] = (buffer[0] - '0' + 1) % 10 + '0';
        vmsplice(1,&iov,1,0);
        // When the sleep is commented, output becomes unordered.
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

launch the code as:

```sh
gcc example.c
./a.out | cat #The pipe is mandatory for vmsplice
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand [`vmsplice`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vmsplice.2.html), it will hand over the buffer (user memory) to the kernel, so the buffer can not be used anymore by the program.

In your case, your buffer is even not on the heap but on the stack. I wonder that it doesn't crash when the stack memory becomes invalid.